# How to change the gps location into english?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

Hello I am creating an app that is international.I take the gps (country name and city name) from user.After that i am wrting that to database but i only want to write the things in english.When i test my code in my friend's iphone (his iphone's language is Turkish) i saw that the variable comes to database in turkish format so i want Turkey to come to dataabse but it comes Türkiye.Can anybody help me to change all variables into english.

There is NSlocal but i don't know how to change? or can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the placemark's `country` property, you can simple use the `countryCode` for saving into your DB. This will store values like `US` instead of `United States` or `Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika`. In other words: the country code is not locale specific.